# view doesn't load with translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Tags: cocoa

This is my code in a NSViewController to load a subview and add a constraint. The view doesn't load because of the line "view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false" I can't find why.

```
let weddingDataVC = logic.storyboardMain.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "WeddingDataVC")) as! WeddingDataVC
let myView = weddingDataVC.view
self.addChildViewController(weddingDataVC)

self.view.addSubview(myView)

myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([xConstraint])
```

Answer (score 0):

You've lost the Layout Constraint of the Vertical Axis.

```
let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([yConstraint])
```

There are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin, and then it throws an exception.

When you add a subview, it will auto add the missing constraints. If you don't need it, you should add all the constraints by yourself.

[There is more information about debugging auto layout.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH21-SW1)